# Infinispan - Hibernate 2nd Level Cache Cluster Marshaling issue

Tags: jboss, infinispan, hibernate-cache, infinispan-9, infinispan-8

We are trying to configure infinispan as the 2nd level cache for Hibernate in Jboss EAP 7.1 and run the jboss in clustered two node setup.

Lookup for cache elements works, but if we update hibernate entities, then update cache step triggered by infinispan fails on both nodes with marshaling error ( caused by class not found exception ) of that entity we are trying to update.

Here is the configuration :

**In hibernate-cfg.xml**
org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory

**in sample-entity-hbm.xml**

```
 <class name="com.business.standard.StandardCode" table="csc011">

 <cache usage="read-write"/>
```

**in jboss standalone-ha.xml**

```
        <cache-container name="hibernate"  module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <transport channel="hibernate-channel" lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"/>
            <invalidation-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </invalidation-cache>               
        </cache-container>
```

**Error :**

15:02:45,974 WARN  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher] (OOB-20,XXX-53994) ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.business.standard.StandardCode from [Module "org.hibernate.infinispan" from local module loader @64d2d351 (finder: local module finder @1b68b9a4 (roots: C:\jboss-eap-7.1\NodeA\modules,C:\jboss-eap-7.1\NodeA\modules\system\layers\base.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-7.1.5.CP,C:\jboss-eap-7.1\NodeA\modules\system\layers\base,C:\jboss-eap-7.1\DEV\modules))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:123)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:104)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1022)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1355)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:220)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1853)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1767)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.MarshallUtil.unmarshallArray(MarshallUtil.java:159)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.InvalidateCommand.readFrom(InvalidateCommand.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.util.BeginInvalidationCommand.readFrom(BeginInvalidationCommand.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:113)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:89)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:479)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:236)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:149)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:350)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.readFrom(SingleRpcCommand.java:46)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readCommandParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:113)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:173)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:68)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:479)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:236)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:149)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:350)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.objectFromObjectStream(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:101)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.MarshallerAdapter.objectFromBuffer(MarshallerAdapter.java:28)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:163)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:455)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.dispatch(RequestCorrelator.java:406)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:357)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:245)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:738)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1030)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:165)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:390)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:1037)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:234)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1077)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:792)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:433)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:649)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:155)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.up(FD_ALL.java:200)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:325)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:292)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:296)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MPING.up(MPING.java:178)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1658)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$SingleMessageHandler.run(TP.java:1876)

Thanks
Santhosh S

Comment: 1. I believe your cache is starting before the app. Would suggest to do a lazy start. 2. Suggest to use pessimist with "NON_XA", as in:                         <transaction mode="NON_XA" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>

Comment: We have fixed this issue. When using infinispan 2nd level cache within Jboss cluster, we would need the following factory class     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</property>